# JMX Port dynamic allocation

Tags: java, monitoring, jmx

I have 16 Java processes with the same main method and arguments running on one machine.  I wish to monitor these remotely thru JConsole.

Hard coding port numbers like `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=5000` won't work because these processes are using same configuration and they can't work with same port.

Is it possible for the JVM to select a different port dynamically for each of the 16 processes?

Comment: if the jvm selected them dynamically, how would you know what port to connect to?

Answer (score 1):

Using RMI Connector might be the way as you may specify URL of your agent.

In case you'd need it, you may create RMI registry programatically using:

```
java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
```

You may find following unrelated sample useful: [Connecting Through Firewall Using JMX](http://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/connecting_through_firewall_using_jmx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't *think* the oracle jvm supports anything like this.  the only thing that might work is using the port "0", which enables "dynamic" port selection in some rmi related stuff.

Comment: if it run's in dynamic port, how do we know which port it is allocated ?

Comment: @Learnis that's the same question i asked in a comment on the original question above.  i don't have an answer for that.