# Multiple Java Applications using JMX

Tags: java, jmx

I'm very new to JMX, and what I try to achieve is the following: I want to use JMX for monitoring multiple instances of the same Java-Application. The problem is, that this application might be run multiple times at the same time. I need the possibility to monitor the JMX values from another (remote) host.

Example Java-Application:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    while(true) {
      try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("I'm running");
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Compiled using `javac Test.java` and then executed using

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false \
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
Test
```

The application now runs, but I do not know how to connect to this process from `jconsole`: I can use `netstat` to find out the port on which the JVM listens but I cannot connect because I receive a "no such object in table" exception when connecting.

If I run it using

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false \
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1412 \
Test
```

, I can connect to `1.2.3.4:1412` using `jconsole`. **But: I cannot run this application a second time without modifiying the port**, which is quite logical as the application cannot bind to the port a second time.

**How can I run the same application multiple times (with the same commandline!) and then connect to the multiple instances?**

Comment: I think you need to have another process before JMX to get ports, without that I don't think it is possible.

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112052/jmx-port-dynamic-allocation

Comment: I already read this question, but I do not know what I have to do to make it run...

Answer (score 1):

> I can connect to 1.2.3.4:1412 using jconsole. But: I cannot run this application a second time without modifiying the port, which is quite logical as the application cannot bind to the port a second time.

Right each of your JVMs is going to have to live on a different port.

> How can I run the same application multiple times (with the same commandline!) and then connect to the multiple instances?

By running them on a different port:

```
java -Dcom... -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1412 Test
java -Dcom... -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1413 Test
```

You can also use the `port=0` to get a "dynamic" RMI port but I'm not sure how you are going to see that remotely.

You might consider using my [SimpleJMX](http://256stuff.com/sources/simplejmx/) package which makes the whole publishing of JMX beans super easy.  It also allows you to publish JMX to different ports easily and programably.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this would require that I cannot run the same command twice using the same command line. I hoped that there is a possibility that the JVM acquires a random port and I can connect to this port later on.

Comment: That's not how JMX works @theomega.  You need to define the end-point if you want to connect to it from a remote TCP port.  That TCP port needs to be unique.  You also need the port for jconsole to be able to connect to it.  It can't be random.

Comment: What about RMI? Can this be used somehow for this reason? And what about setting the port to `0`. It seems to randomize the port somehow and I'm able to connect to it, perhaps this is a solution?

Comment: I did not know about the port=0 support.  However I don't see how that's going to work remotely since you still need to find the port to be able to connect to it @theomega.

Comment: Yep, thats the problem with the port=0 setting.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer on your other question:
[Enable JMX in Hadoop Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813385/enable-jmx-in-hadoop-job/19596009#19596009)

You can set port=0 and then turn up logging such that you can see the port that was chosen as indicated here:
https://forums.oracle.com/message/4798165#4798165

Comment: If [JDK-8172384](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8172384) is fixed, you'll be able to see the port without modifying the logging configuration.