# Enable JMX in Hadoop Job

Tags: java, jmx

I want to enable JMX monitoring for my hadoop job (**not for the JobTracker, DataNode or something else, for the actual job**). I'm searching for a possibility where I can connect from my local machine to the host/cluster/node where the job is running using `jconsole` and retrieve some monitoring values. So I need remote access to JMX.

I tried to add some options to `MAPRED_MAP_TASK_JAVA_OPTS` and `MAPRED_REDUCE_TASK_JAVA_OPTS`:

1. Adding 
   `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=fals-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` does not help me as I do not know how to connect to JMX using `jconsole`. A port gets opened, but whenever I try to connect using `jconsole`, I get a "no such object in table" error.
2. `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=fals-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1412` does work as expected: I can connect to `hostname:1412` using `jconsole`. **Main problem here: As the mapper/reducer might get run multiple times on the same node and the port cannot be used twice, the second time my mapper/reducer is started fails with an exception.**

Is there any solution which allows me to use JMX in a hadoop job? This question is related to [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812792/multiple-java-applications-using-jmx) I just asked which tries to formulate the problem at another level.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your question can be found here:
https://forums.oracle.com/message/4798165#4798165

Basically, you can use -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=0 and then check the log to find the port the JMX Connector Server is listening on.

One of the tricks to doing this is that you have to change the log level of the root logger to CONFIG.  Depending on the configuration of your cluster and your level of access, it may be difficult to modify the logging.properties file to do this.

Another route would be to specify java.util.logging.config.class to point to your own class to do the logging configuration.  You can easily distribute such a class with your code.  Then it should be easy to change the root log level without access to the local filesystem.

I have not actually tested this approach on a Hadoop cluster yet, but I expect it should work.

Comment: If [JDK-8172384](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8172384) gets resolved this will be a fair bit simpler as you'll be able to set port=0 and see the port in the log without having to muck with changing the logging configuration.

Answer (score 0):

you have to setup your /etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh accordingly:

http://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2012/09/21/enabling-jmx-monitoring-for-hadoop-and-hive/

However, I wonder if this is the best way of doing this: if you want to observe specific behaviour, you might be better off isolating a specific input file and debugging against a local pseudo-cluster, and if you want system metrics you could do worse than give Ganglia a lookm as it is pretty mauch already built into hadoop:

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/GangliaMetrics

Comment: As I tried to explain in my first sentence, I want to monitor a job, not the NameNode or the JobTracker. The blog post you mention specified "Hadoop’s NameNode and JobTracker expose interesting metrics and statistics over the JMX."...
I also need the possibility to reconfigure Log4J using JMX, so ganglia wont help me, I really need JMX.

Answer (score 0):

For those still looking for an answer, setting `MAPRED_MAP_TASK_JAVA_OPTS` config doesn't actually work. Instead, you will have to set this config on the program driver (Runner) so that it propagates it to the mappers/reducers:

```
configuration.set("mapreduce.map.java.opts", "-Xmx1600m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8008");
```

Likewise, for the reducer, you can set the variable to `mapreduce.reduce.java.opts`.

To see if it worked. Just log into one of the machines and run `ps aux | grep 8008` to see if the JMX port was set correctly.